# Django allauth social login(google OAuth 2) - limit list of domains

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, django-allauth

I have implemented social login(provider-google) using [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google) for my web application. I want to allow only a limited domains to the application. The following is my settings for allauth

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'mbaweb.socialaccount_adapter.NoNewUsersAccountAdapter'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
            'hd': 'abc.com'
        }
    }
}
```

By using 'hd' parameter I am able to allow only the accounts with domain 'abc.com'. It restricts all other domain accounts.

But my requirement is to allow a list of domains to the application

for example:- `allowed_domains = ['abc.com', 'xyz.co.in', 'pqr.com']`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can use `ALLOWED_HOSTS =['abc.com', 'def.com', ...]` in your settings.py

Comment: Google specific, all-auth configurations: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google


I think, removing the `hd` key from `AUTH_PARAMS` should solve your issue.

Comment: If I remove hd, it will allow all the domains to the application

Answer (score 5):

The approach I use is to write a custom `SocialAccountAdapter` which returns
false for `is_open_for_signup` in certain conditions.

In settings, add this:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.auth.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter'
```

Obviously, change the path `myapp.auth` to fit your code.

In the appropriate `adapters.py` file, add something like this:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter


def email_domain(email):
    """Extracts the domain from an email address.

    Warning: this is simplified and you may want a true email address parser.
    """
    return email.split('@')[-1]


# Note: this would be better in settings.py
allowed_signup_domains = [
    'abc.com',
    'seconddomain.com',
    'etcetc.com',
]


class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def is_open_for_signup(self, request, sociallogin):
        if email_domain(sociallogin.user.email) not in allowed_signup_domains:
            return False
        return super(SocialAccountAdapter, self).is_open_for_signup(request, sociallogin)
```

The approach isn't perfect but does the job and gives the user a somewhat "graceful" failure.

Comment: I am using the same method for now. It will show the error message, but the use will be logged in to the account. If the user want to use some other account to login, he/she will have to manually go to the already logged in account and do a logout. Then sign in with a different account. Also once we got the error message, The url will be the oauth2 callback url. It will cause more confusion if the user refresh the page.

Comment: I want to control this before the user gets logged in to an invalid account.

Comment: I've re-tested to be sure and I confirm that when the `is_open_for_signup()` method returns False, the user is _not_ logged in and _no_ account for that user is created. They do stop on the callback URL and if they reload that page it says "social network failure". Not perfectly elegant but functional and  clear.